# Can you run SAS without actualy computing the table results

Tags: sas, enterprise-guide

I am working with a gigantic database and SAS wont let me alter the queries without first running the entire SAS file and calculating everything which takes eternities.

Is there a way of running SAS in a way I can alter the queries and run them without really computing them. In a way what I mean is if there is a way that a query can create a dummy empty table so I can alter further queries, so that I only have to run the project at the end of my changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1)You can try to use this code:

```
data want;
   if 0 then set have;
   stop;
run;
```

It creates table that has structure of `have` table but without data. So, you can use this table for queries.

2) Or if you want to use couple rows of data in your queries, use [`obs`](https://v8doc.sas.com/sashtml/lgref/z0131154.htm):

```
data want;
   set have(obs=5);
run;
```

This solution you can implement in query builder in SAS EG.

- right button mouse click on source table in query builder

[image: query builder]

- properties
- in table `options` type `obs=5`

[image: properties window]

Comment: I am still quite new to SAS so ive been using the UI and not writing the code by hand, is there a way of doing what youve said on the query builder UI. Just got deadlines and using the UI will lead to less errors

Comment: @PedroLopes what software do you use? is it sas enterprise guide?

Comment: Thank you a lot that makes my job so much faster